# Is it possible to make HDRI following camera?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, hdri, world, vector-mapping

I made a landscape with an HDRI that I want to use on the final render. But the thing is as I navigate the scene via camera,  the World stays the same, which makes everything completely fake. I know I could do some manual animation of HDRI by animating Mapping node, but it likely wont look good. Is there a way to make HDRI react on camera movement automatically? I am talking about zooms and such, not only rotation (which already works). I`m using EEVEE btw.

Comment: I don't think you'll get what you want through editing the world environment. Try making a "sky sphere" around your scene using a sphere mesh,. and project your HDRI onto that..

Comment: I did it with Blender 2.5 and thought there`d be a better solution nowadays but thanks!